# Multiple HttpPost method in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my web application I have a form where user can send SMS to any phone. The action is declared something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Massages massages)
{
   // called the webservice
   return View(massages);
}
```

This works fine.

There is web service which sends the SMS message to the client (i.e. their phone). In this web service call we also have to provide a PostBackUrl, so we could see the response which client has provided.

This response is coming in form of JSON and HttpPost.

I am puzzled how declare such function.

```
//It is wrong but It might be something like this.

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReplyBack(JSON reply)
{
    return View(reply);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are close, you should just define the structure of the "reply" argument as a C# class and ASP.NET will parse the JSON postback.
So do

```
public class JSONRequest
{
    property MessageId as Int
    property Sender AS String
}

[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ReplyBack(JSONRequest request)
 {
    //query database with request.MessageId
    return View(reply);
 }
```

I changed the name of your argument to request because, unless I am not following your question correctly, you need to call another webservice to get replies. So it does not make sense to make a request to ReplyBack with an JSON argument called reply, the response is the reply in this case, so ReplyBack gets the request arguments and builds the reply as a response. Also I would rename your ReplyBack method to GetReply as it should make more sense to other developers.

Comment: Thank you Brian. The webservice will call back at this function because I declared in my webservice Call PostBackUrl= www.somewebist\Home\ReplyBack.  Now I will receive response at this function when someone replies back the SMS message. Now I have to convert request to an object so I could publish the reply from the user.

Comment: So, if I am following your comment, the conversion of the request to an object is already done for you by ASP.NET. It will parse you json post request to ReplyBack and create an instance of JSONRequest and populate the matching properties. So when ReplyBack is called from javascript with a correctly formatted and populated JSON object, you will get a correct C# instantiation of the JSONRequest object used in my code example within the ReplyBack method.